# Paypal - Capture Order - TypeError: strtolower(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, int given

Tags: laravel, api, paypal, payment, guzzle

I am trying to use PayPal as a payment method on my website. I am using Laravel framework and GuzzleHttp package. Creating an order runs smoothly. Problem comes when trying to capture an order using id.

```
php artisan tinker
>>> $paypal = new App\Services\PayPalService;
=> App\Services\PayPalService {#3447}
>>> $paypal->createOrder(500.00, 'EUR');
=> {#3478                                                                                       
     +"id": "3NK71944KB9544808",                                                                
     +"status": "CREATED",                                                                      
     +"links": [                                                                                
       {#3476                                                                                   
         +"href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/3NK71944KB9544808",        
         +"rel": "self",                                                                        
         +"method": "GET",                                                                      
       },                                                                                       
       {#3461                                                                                   
         +"href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=3NK71944KB9544808",         
         +"rel": "approve",                                                                     
         +"method": "GET",                                                                      
       },                                                                                       
       {#3472                                                                                   
         +"href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/3NK71944KB9544808",        
         +"rel": "update",                                                                      
         +"method": "PATCH",                                                                    
       },                                                                                       
       {#3465                                                                                   
         +"href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/3NK71944KB9544808/capture",
         +"rel": "capture",                                                                     
         +"method": "POST",                                                                     
       },                                                                                       
     ],                                                                                         
   }
>>> $paypal->capture("3NK71944KB9544808");
TypeError: strtolower(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, int given
```

Consuming API code:

```
public function makeRequest($method, $requestURL, $queryParams = [], $formParams = [], $headers = [], $isJSONRequest = false)
{
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => $this->baseUri,
    ]);

    if (method_exists($this, 'resolveAuthorization')) {
        $this->resolveAuthorization($queryParams, $formParams, $headers);
    }

    $response = $client->request($method, $requestURL, [
        $isJSONRequest ? 'json' : 'form_params' => $formParams,
        'headers' => $headers,
        'query' => $queryParams,
    ]);

    if (method_exists($this, 'decodeResponse')) {
        return $this->decodeResponse($response->getBody()->getContents());
    }

    return $response->getBody()->getContents();
}
```

Capturing an order code:

```
public function captureOrder($id)
{
   return $this->makeRequest('POST', "/v2/checkout/orders/$id/capture", [], [], [
       "Content-Type: application/json",
   ]);
}
```

Comment: I found an error, might be the issue change `"/v2/checkout/orders/$id/capture"` to `"/v2/checkout/orders/{$id}/capture"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I switched to PayPal HTTP client and it worked just fine.